# Error while invoking a higher-order function

Tags: haskell, ghci

I wrote a higher-order Haskell function as follows,

```
higherOrderFun f p xs = (map f) (filter p xs)
```

It works for the following

```
higherOrderFun (\x -> 2 * x) odd [1..4]

but throws an error for

higherOrderFun sin odd [1..4]
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
No instance for (Show b0) arising from a use of ‘print’
The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  ...plus 23 others
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Any pointers for debugging?

Comment: I'm getting a different error.  Not entirely sure how to parse it, but my error seems to arise from the fact that the result of `odd [1..4]` is an `Integral` list and `sin` expects `Floating` arguments.

Comment: This is probably a difference between evaluating in GHCI and using it in e.g. a `.hs` file. GHCI goes to some effort to decide function types as late as possible for the purposes of experimentation, leading to errors like the OP sees. GHC attempts to assign one (possibly polymorphic) type to higherOrderFun, and fails when it can't infer a single type that matches both uses of the function.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta , I tried it on ghci. Were you triyng it in ghci as well?

Comment: @SreenathNannat, yes, I was doing it in ghci.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is the conceptual interaction of `odd` and `sin`. You can't take the `sin` of a non-floating point, and a floating point can't be `odd` (or `even`, for that matter). GHCI tries to give you the benefit of the doubt for the purposes of exploration, so it doesn't assign a concrete type to the output of `higherOrderFun sin odd [1..4]`, preferring to infer a type which can conceptually not exist (namely `(Integral b, Floating b) => [b]`). This comes back to bite you when you try to print the value, as the non-existent inferred type can (of course) not have an instance of `Show`. This is not restricted to `show`: any attempt to assign a concrete type (calling `odd`, manually assigning with e.g. `:: Double`, etc) fails.

GHC is much more picky. If you stick this in a `.hs` file and try to compile it, GHC will complain because it can't infer a coherent type for `higherOrderFun`

```
module Main where

higherOrderFun f p xs = (map f) (filter p xs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let x = higherOrderFun (\x -> 2 * x) odd [1..4]
        y = higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1..4]
    print (x, y)

{-
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/test.hs, /tmp/test.o )

/tmp/test.hs:8:29:
    No instance for (Floating b0) arising from a use of ‘sin’
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include y :: [b0] (bound at /tmp/test.hs:8:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    In the first argument of ‘higherOrderFun’, namely ‘(sin)’
    In the expression: higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1 .. 4]
    In an equation for ‘y’: y = higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1 .. 4]

/tmp/test.hs:8:34:
    No instance for (Integral b0) arising from a use of ‘odd’
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include y :: [b0] (bound at /tmp/test.hs:8:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral GHC.Types.Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the second argument of ‘higherOrderFun’, namely ‘odd’
    In the expression: higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1 .. 4]
    In an equation for ‘y’: y = higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1 .. 4]

/tmp/test.hs:8:38:
    No instance for (Enum b0)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘1 .. 4’
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include y :: [b0] (bound at /tmp/test.hs:8:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Enum Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Enum Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Enum (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 7 others
    In the third argument of ‘higherOrderFun’, namely ‘[1 .. 4]’
    In the expression: higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1 .. 4]
    In an equation for ‘y’: y = higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1 .. 4]

/tmp/test.hs:8:39:
    No instance for (Num b0) arising from the literal ‘1’
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include y :: [b0] (bound at /tmp/test.hs:8:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 1
    In the third argument of ‘higherOrderFun’, namely ‘[1 .. 4]’
    In the expression: higherOrderFun (sin) odd [1 .. 4]

/tmp/test.hs:9:5:
    No instance for (Show b0) arising from a use of ‘print’
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include y :: [b0] (bound at /tmp/test.hs:8:9)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 24 others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (x, y)
    In the expression:
      do { let x = higherOrderFun (\ x -> ...) odd ...
               y = higherOrderFun (sin) odd ...;
           print (x, y) }
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = do { let x = ...
                     ....;
                 print (x, y) }
-}
```

Regarding `map sin [1..4]` "working": While `map sin [1..4]` prints something, it does not have the same restriction placed by `odd`. GHCI will simply infer `[1..4]` is a list of `Double`s and act accordingly.

#### Debugging

The best way (I find) to debug this is with the `:t` and `:i` commands in GHCI. An example GHCI session:

```
Prelude PrettyGHCI> let higherOrderFun f p xs = (map f) (filter p xs)
Prelude PrettyGHCI> :t higherOrderFun sin odd [1..4]
higherOrderFun sin odd [1..4] :: (Integral b, Floating b) => [b]
```

Right off, this type looks fishy to me. There should be no types which are both `Integral` and `Floating`. We can check this with `:i`:

```
Prelude PrettyGHCI> :i Floating
instance Floating Float
instance Floating Double
Prelude PrettyGHCI> :i Integral
instance Integral Integer
instance Integral Int
```

I cleaned up the output a bit, so it should be obvious here that there is no overlap in the types inhabiting `Floating` and `Integral`.

At this point, you have essentially two choices

1. Give up
2. Convince the types to play nicely

Giving up is not a valid option, so we convince the types to play nicely:

```
Prelude PrettyGHCI> :t higherOrderFun (sin . fromIntegral) odd [1..4]
higherOrderFun (sin . fromIntegral) odd [1..4] :: Floating b => [b]
```

Which gives us a nice, valid, polymorphic type. The two type inhabitants of `Floating` (`Float` and `Double`) both have `Show` instances, so your work here is done.

Note that the reason we can do this is because all `Floating` types are required to be `Fractional`. `Fractional` provides a function `fromRational :: Rational -> a`. `Integral` types are required to be `Real`, and `Real` provides a function `toRational :: a -> Rational`. `fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b` is simply defined as `fromRational . toRational`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look, `sin` has type `sin :: Floating a => a -> a` but your list has type `(filter odd [1..4]) :: Integral a => [a]`. Thus, you encounter a failure.

But,

`higherOrderFun (sin . fromIntegral) odd [1..4]`

Returns

`[0.8414709848078965,0.1411200080598672]`

Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

`odd` only works on `Integral` values (values of a type that has an `instance` for the `Integral` type class). `sin` only works on `Floating` ones. The type of `higherOrderFun sin odd [1..4]` is

```
>:t higherOrderFun sin odd [1..4]
higherOrderFun sin odd [1..4] :: (Integral b, Floating b) => [b]
```

To use this, you'd need a type that's both `Integral` and `Floating`, and none exists in the base library (nor should any). You can make a value of any `Num` type, and thus any `Floating` type, from a value of an `Integral` type with `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`

```
>:t higherOrderFun  (sin . fromIntegral) odd [1..4]
higherOrderFun (sin . fromIntegral) odd [1..4] :: Floating b => [b]
```

This only requires a `Floating` instance for the result. ghci will evaluate this with `Double`, its default for an unknown type that needs a `Floating` instance.

```
Prelude> higherOrderFun (sin . fromIntegral) odd [1..4]
[0.8414709848078965,0.1411200080598672]
```

Comment: But ```map sin [1..4]``` works without any error. That is confusing me.

Comment: `[1..4] :: (Num t, Enum t) => [t]` that is, it can provide values for any type that has both a `Num` and `Enum` instance. As a result the type of `map sin [1..4]` is `map sin [1..4] :: (Floating b, Enum b) => [b]`. `Double`, which is the default type for the `Floating` typeclass, also has an `Enum` instance. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromThenTo

Comment: I recommend reading Chapter 3 of Learn You a Haskell, Types and Typeclasses. http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses